# How to cherry-pick commit correctly

Tags: git, command-line, branch, cherry-pick

I have to cherry-pick commit to issue-7044 from issue-7044a branch and when I run

```
git cherry-pick <commit-hash>
```

I receive:

```
On branch issue-7044
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/issue-7044'.

You are currently cherry-picking commit <hash>.
  (all conflicts fixed: run "git cherry-pick --continue")
  (use "git cherry-pick --skip" to skip this patch)
  (use "git cherry-pick --abort" to cancel the cherry-pick operation)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
The previous cherry-pick is now empty, possibly due to conflict resolution.
If you wish to commit it anyway, use:

    git commit --allow-empty

Otherwise, please use 'git cherry-pick --skip'
```

And no changes in repository folder, what should I do?
(I need to copy all files from that commit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means:

- either the commit cherry-picked from issue-7044a is already part of the issue-7044 branch (through a merge for instance)
- or the changes introduced by that commits are already applied to the target branch

In both instance, there is nothing for Git to apply.

Comment: In other words: all the files are already there